# mocking parent internal dependency

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, mocking, mockito

I want to write unit test for service methods but my service is written in a generic way. My service extends a generic service and in generic service, we have custom generic repository dependency and a generic repository.

```
public class MyService extends GenericService<MyService, Long> {
    private final MyServiceRepository myServiceRepo;
    private final AnotherRepository anotherRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyServiceRepository myServiceRepo, AnotherRepository anotherRepository) 
    {
         super(myServiceRepo , MyEntity.class);
         this.myServiceRepo= myServiceRepo;
         this.anotherRepository = anotherRepository ;
    }

    // specific custom service method for MyEntity service

}
```

==============================================================

```
public class GenericService<T,ID extends Serializable>{

    @Autowired
    private CustomGenericRepository customRepository;

    private GenericRepository<T, ID> genericRepository;

    public GenericService(GenericRepository<T, ID> genericRepository , Class entity) {
        this.genericRepository = genericRepository;
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Response add(T t) {

        Optional o= genericRepository.findById(id); 

        if(o!=null){
            t1 = genericRepository.save(t);
            return "adding data is succussfully" 
        }else{
             throw new RecordAlreadyExistException(entityClass, "id", getId(t));
        }
     } 
}
```

In this code `GenericRepository` inherited `JpaRepository`.

My test class is :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GroupServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private MyEntityRepository repo;
    @Mock
    private AnotherRepository anotherRepo;
    @Mock
    private CustomGenericRepository  customGenericRepository;
    @Mock
    private GenericRepository<MyEntity,Long> genericRepository ;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void testServiceAddMethod(){
        MyEntity data = new MyEntity();
        data.setId(1L);
        Mockito.when(repo.save(data)).thenReturn(data);
            Mockito.when(genericRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(optional.empty());
        service.add(data);
        Mockito.verify(repo,Mockito.times(1)).save(data);
    }
}
```

I using this maven dependency :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```

How should I solve this problem now? Is there a way to mock `GenericRepository`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to refactor at least some of code code to make this test work.

1. You try to inject Mocks into `MyService` class.

   However  your class has a constructor with two parameters:

   - MyServiceRepository myServiceRepo
   - AnotherRepository anotherRepository

   This implies that Mockito will use [`Constructor Injection`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html), which limits you to the injection of only those two fields. `CustomGenericRepository` would not be injected.
2. Neither would be `MyEntityRepository`. However this class seems to be unrelated to your class under test?
3. Also it is not quite clear where your `NullPointerException` is coming from.
    (Consider posting the fullstacktrace).
   I assume it comes from this line
   `Mockito.when(genericRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(optional);` 

   `optional` is `null` when you return it, so when the method is invoked you call the `get` method on it, which causes the `NPE`. You'll want to change that to an `Optional.empty()` instead.


   Under the assumption that `genericRepository.findById(id)` is supposed to return a `Optional<MyEntity>` you will have to change your code, because you won't get `null` out of it. Instead your code should look like this:

```
Optional<T> t1 = genericRepository.findById(id);
if (t1.isEmpty()) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

4. Besides all that, for a simple test of the `add` method, you would only need to inject a mock for `genericRepositry` (which is identical to `myServiceRepo`). I am not sure however what you are trying to do and if the code is complete so I decided to point out the previous issues anyway.

(I assume `data` and `dto` are the same and its just a typo on your end)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GroupServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testServiceAddMethod() {

        GenericRepository genericRepository = Mockito.mock(GenericRepository.class);
        AnotherRepository anotherRepository = Mockito.mock(AnotherRepository.class);

        MyEntity data = new MyEntity();
        data.setId(1L);

        Mockito.when(genericRepository.save(data)).thenReturn(data);
        Mockito.when(genericRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        MyService service = new MyService(genericRepository, anotherRepository);
        service.add(data);

        Mockito.verify(genericRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(data);
    }
}
```

So this test should do, if you just adjust the handling of `Optional`.
(And you'll probably want to change the return of the add method, but I assume that is just placeholder code)

Also your `MyEntity` should have a proper implementation of the `equals` and `hashCode` method, so that java identifies theses objects as identical.

`@SpringBootTest` does not seem to be required for this UnitTest.

Note that for simplicity (and better readability) I decide to inject the Mocks manual, it should also work if you just use
(In this case all other dependencies would be null):

```
@Mock
GenericRepository<MyEntity,Long> myServiceRepo;

@InjectMocks
MyService service;
```

Comment: Hi . thanks for your answer. but I have to answer some of your ambiguities. 1-This code is a part of the original code that is shortened for lengthy question. 2- I know about constructor injection but since I have to get another amount in the constructor, then I can't use it. 3-this version of mockito don't have MockitoMock . 3-java.util.Optional returns an NoSuchElementException error  when it has no value and don't have isEmpty(). 4-MyEntityRepository use for my custom query because parent class is shared between several entity .

Comment: I update my code and resolve my problem . Thank @second for the tips you have explained

Comment: `MockitoMock` was a typo, [`Optional.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty()) was added in Java 11, if you use a older version [`isPresent() == false`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent()) will do.